# Create a separate zip from many folders

Tags: macos, mac, zip, automator

I have a many folders with files for project.
I need:

1. Create a zip from folder "X"
2. Move Zip in the folder "X"
3. Name of Zip must be "X"

I'm a Mac OS user. How I can automate the process?

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to provide a sample before and after directory structure? That might make it easier to tell what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make zip files with a command line, then the Unix-like shell features should make this rather doable.  The following ought to work with Info-Zip.  Start by getting to a terminal.

`cd`   *somewhere*`/CA33-1/..`
`pwd`
`for x in * ; do echo sample $x ; echo sample2 $x; zip $x/$x.zip $x ; done`

That's a bit sloppy, because the "for" command will try to work on files, and not just sub-directories.  However, I'm presuming that the "zip" command will fail for files.